# How to setstylesheet of widgets individually stored in list

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

below is just a pseudo code what i am trying to do.
so there is a button which i press to add more buttons but i store button widget in a list, which i can access by its index number.

```
# initialize class: this is just a pseudo code of what i am trying to do
       def __init__(self,parent=None):
          self.ButtonWidgetList=list()
          self.i=0
          self.MakeButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton(self) #assume this button is displayed and works
          self.MakeButton.clicked.connect(self.NextButton) # assume this button calls Function NextButton

      def NextButton(self):
          
          self.ButtonWidgetList[self.i]=QtWidgets.QPushButton()
          self.i=self.i+1
```

How can i access individual buttons stored in list by .setStyleSheet as i need it to change its image on press for example:

```
self.ButtonWidgetList[self.i].setStyleSheet("QPushButton#ButtonWidgetList{\n"
"border-image:url(:/imageA)};\n"
"QPushButton#ButtonWidgetList:pressed{\n"
"border-image:url(:/imageB)};\n"
```

i hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set stylesheet individually for each button in the list or use the same stylesheet for all those buttons?

Comment: @musicamante Individually,  Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Uhm, now after your edit I'm still a bit confused. You're already setting the stylesheet for that widget, what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: yep its confusing, i know. I am sorry for that. So if you see ```.setStyleSheet("QPushButton# ButtonWidgetList    <== this here is the target widget which i cant access. As this is all string and i believe it cant grab from a listed widgets.

Comment: I don't understand. You are already setting the stylesheet for that button, so remove the "#" selector and just use `self.ButtonWidgetList[self.i].setStyleSheet("QPushButton { ... }")`.

Comment: Thanks, didnt realize. it was that easy. I was following the documentation and ended up writing correct code but logically wrong.

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered? Thank you so much :)

Comment: It wouldn't have worked anyway: the `#` selector is for the [`objectName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property, Qt doesn't know anything about the name you set for an object in python (and it couldn't even know it). It would have worked only if you used something like: `self.ButtonWidgetList[self.i].setObjectName('ButtonWidgetList')`

Comment: I understand it now. 
Thanks @musicamante for your help. really appreciated!

Comment: I cannot set this as answered because there's no answer (and, frankly, I consider this mostly as a "conceptual typo"). I suggest you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand how StackOverflow works, and also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions (a suggestion: making a good question takes *a lot* of time and efforts; don't rush, take your time and ensure that what you're asking is clear).

Comment: Surely, Thanks. I will make sure next time.